# How to read a jpeg from disk and instantiate it as 'werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage'?

Tags: python, file, werkzeug

```
python  3.10.11
werkzeug  2.3.7
```

I have a jpeg in `/mnt/dragon.jpeg`

I want to write unit test for a method, which has `werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage` as input, and behavior is save it to  a path.

I try to instantiate it with codes below:

```py
import os
from werkzeug.datastructures import FileStorage

PATH = "/mnt/dragon.jpeg"

def get_file(filepath: str) -> FileStorage:
    filename = os.path.basename(filepath)
    with open(filepath, 'rb') as file:
        return FileStorage(file, name=filename)

file = get_file(PATH)
```

The ipython instance output are:

```py
In [8]: file
Out[8]: <FileStorage: '/mnt/dragon.jpeg' (None)>

In [9]: file.save("/mnt/saved.jpeg")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[9], line 1
----> 1 file.save("/mnt/saved.jpeg")

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/werkzeug/datastructures/file_storage.py:129, in FileStorage.save(self, dst, buffer_size)
    126     close_dst = True
    128 try:
--> 129     copyfileobj(self.stream, dst, buffer_size)
    130 finally:
    131     if close_dst:

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/shutil.py:195, in copyfileobj(fsrc, fdst, length)
    193 fdst_write = fdst.write
    194 while True:
--> 195     buf = fsrc_read(length)
    196     if not buf:
    197         break

ValueError: read of closed file
```

How to make the `werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage` file can be saved outside the scope of `open`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [in-memory bytes buffer(`io.BytesIO`)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO). The current problem with your code is that python closes the underlying file as soon as the `with` block completes its execution.

```
import os
import io
from werkzeug.datastructures import FileStorage

PATH = "/mnt/dragon.jpeg"

def get_file(filepath: str) -> FileStorage:
    filename = os.path.basename(filepath)
    with open(filepath, 'rb') as file:
        return FileStorage(io.BytesIO(file.read()), name=filename)

file = get_file(PATH)
```

Comment: Awesome!!! Thank you for your solution and clear explanation, I found using 'file = open(filepath, 'rb')' instead of 'with' block also works on my side.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_file(filepath: str) -> FileStorage:
    filename = os.path.basename(filepath)
    file = open(filepath, 'rb')
    return FileStorage(file, name=filename)
```

Changing function to this solved this issue

Comment: You probably have to call the [`close` function to close the underlaying file](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/f3c803b3ade485a45f12b6d6617595350c0f03e2/src/werkzeug/datastructures/file_storage.py#L134-L139)

Comment: Oh yes, you are right, I agree that your approach is closer to the best practice for this case.